# Two version of "it.next()" + "it.nextIndex()" but in difference order, why result is different

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

I'm trying to learn the ListIterator interface. I have came up with two version of the code,

```
List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(11,22,33,44));

ListIterator<Integer> it = list1.listIterator();

while (it.hasNext()){

    //version 1
    System.out.println("value: " + it.next() + " index: " + it.nextIndex());

    //version 2
    System.out.println("index: " + it.nextIndex() + " value: " + it.next());
}
```

Result of version 1:

```
value: 11 index: 1
value: 22 index: 2
value: 33 index: 3
value: 44 index: 4
```

Result of version 2:

```
index: 0 value: 11
index: 1 value: 22
index: 2 value: 33
index: 3 value: 44
```

I was expecting the result to be the same, but obviously they are not. Could someone please tell me why?

Comment: Why doesn't ```nextIndex``` increase the index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `it.next()` first, `it.nextIndex()` will return the index of the element after `it.next()`s result, since it.next() will return the value at the current index and then subsequently increment the index.

**Visual example:**

---

`it.next()` first:

```
      v
index 0  1  2  3
value 11 22 33 44

call it.next() -> returns 11, increments index by 1

         v
index 0  1  2  3
value 11 22 33 44

call it.nextIndex() -> returns 1
```

---

`it.nextIndex()` first:

```
      v
index 0  1  2  3
value 11 22 33 44

call it.nextIndex() -> returns 0

      v   
index 0  1  2  3
value 11 22 33 44

call it.nextIndex() -> returns 11, increments index by 1

         v
index 0  1  2  3
value 11 22 33 44
```

Comment: Why doesn't ```nextIndex``` increase the index ?

Comment: @DachuanZhao Because sometimes you want the next index without iterating. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html#nextIndex()

Answer (score 1):

The string concatenation expressions are evaluated from left to right. This means in

```
"value: " + it.next() + " index: " + it.nextIndex()
```

`nextIndex()` is called after `next()` is called, in

```
"index: " + it.nextIndex() + " value: " + it.next()
```

it's the other way round.

Since `next()` moves the position of the iterator, the value returned by `nextIndex()` is different in both cases.